# What are my scripting options for a library/framework for building a web app

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I am investigating building a web app.

I know systems like Twitter Bootstrap provide a great starting point for front end design but what are the options for back end, preferably PHP/mySQL but I am open to anything. I have searched around a bit but I am not sure I have the right terminology because all of my searches have brought up nothing close to what I need, so I can only assume I'm looking in the wrong places.

There are plenty of scripts out there that will create a youtube clone for example; and what I need *will* be similar to this but it will not be video site. My app will be geared up more towards managing and creating lists, information, tags, files ( like .doc .txt etc maybe ). I haven't actually gotten the content part worked out fully yet and I don't expect the base system to be able to handle that part necessarily but what I would like  for now is if I could find some library/framework that would allow me to experiment with different content configurations.

**What I need from this framework specifically is some kind of system whereby people could register and thus have a login, profile page and have variuous (private) things associated with their account** ... (  again I'm not sure what 'things' yet but probably lists and possibly files of some kind). I will eventually probably need some kind of capacity to share things between members. There seems to be a library/script for everything else out there so I thought there might be something for the basis of a membership system.

So

a) can someone suggest the correct terminology I would search google for this - I was trying "portal" script and membership site but I got nowhere

b) does such a thing exist and can anyone suggest anything in particular.

One more important thing. The project is in the very early stages and has no budget so I am pretty much limited to Open Source Freeware, though I welcome any paid for solutions regardless

PS I have developed with WordPress for years now and I know I could probably squeeze this out of WordPress with a few plugins and CPT work but I really feel it might be asking too much and I'll get scaling issues earlier than I need to.

Comment: I respect the downvotes but I don't actually understand ... feedback appreciated please.

Comment: The downvotes are because this is a question that can't really have an accepted answer. You'll just get opinionated answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Comment: Actually I was hoping for a list of options not opinions, but I know what you mean

Comment: N/P I didn't downvote (I haven't used this site enough to be able to)

Comment: how are  options different to opinions for this question ?

Comment: Well I suppose options by definition would be independent of opinion. I think in this case opinions are a list of what someone thinks I SHOULD be using whereas options would be a list of what you think I COULD be using. Options really don't normally lead to debate (unless someone decides to add their opinion) ... opinions of course attract debate. Actually I keep bumping into this in SO ... I can't quite understand it but I do respect that SO is better with debate out of the answers.

Comment: i don't share your opinion on the differences to options ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to determine what language you will build the system in. 
PHP/MySQL frameworks include Yii, Symphony, Zend and more. Google PHP Frameworks.

if you want to go with Ruby with a rails framework then you can look into that. Rails for Zombies is a good place to start learning Ruby On Rails.

You are referring to this as a "Portal" but I would not be searching for that. I would be looking at web applications. I build a lot of these types of applications in Yii framework with PHP. If you are familiar with wordpress, then perhaps PHP would be a better option. If you do go with PHP on a Yii framework, then consider learning how to use the Gii code generator. This will help you make tables and lists and manage records. I started with this book: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1847199585?tag=gii20f-20&camp=0&creative=0&linkCode=as1&creativeASIN=1847199585&adid=0BHF2HS6FNS82M85KJQT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199585) and it showed me everything I needed to know about the framework. It also is good if you are still quite new to PHP and Object Oriented Programming.